# Cacti Graphing CPU / Memory utilization over time

Tags: windows, performance, redhat, cacti

Our shop already has several systems already added to Cacti for monitoring of network utilization.

I was wondering: Is there a way we could use Cacti to track RAM/CPU utilization over time? I have done some cursory searching but couldn't find anything. I'm hoping SF can send me in the right direction.

OS: RHEL and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Install the net-snmp package, then configure cacti to look at it.

Here are my notes on [configuring snmp for cacti.](http://wiki.xdroop.com/space/snmp/Sample+snmpd.conf+for+cacti+use)